# How can an NSDateComponents be stored into NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to store an NSDateComponents to NSUserDefaults, so need to wrap it in an NSData first, how can this be done?

Alternatively is there another way of storing an NSDateComponent to user defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDateComponents` conforms to `NSCoding` protocol, so you can use `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` to do the job. Here is some sample code:

```
NSDateComponents *cmp = ...;
//Encoding
NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData data];

NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

[archiver encodeObject:cmp];
[archiver finishEncoding];

//Decoding
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];

NSDateComponents *decoded = [unarchiver decodeObject];

[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

Comment: This can be done with much less code by using the class methods `archivedDataWithRootObject:` and `unarchiveObjectWithData:`.